# Is it possible to construct a PCRE UTF-8 regex which matches 3 or more non-consecutive UTF codepoints

Tags: c++, windows, pcre

Good morning, We are trying to match the German string 'DAS tausendschÃ¶ne JungfrÃ¤ulein tausendschÃ§ne' using the C/C++ PCRE regex `"\x{00F6}.*\x{00E4}.*\x{00E7}"`. The PCRE regex matches only once beginning at byte  positions 14 and 43. Is our PCRE regex correct or should it be corrected? THank you.

Comment: Seems that you are having a codepage issue in your posting here?

Comment: Uwe Keim, We are using the standard Latin codepoint table. Thank you. P.S. We know that the PCRE REgex works correctly on '\x{00F6}.*\x{00E4}' with the German String 'DAS tausendschÃ¶ne JungfrÃ¤ulein and matches 4 times.

Comment: What you have there is UTF-8 interpreted as Latin 1. You *do* have an encoding problem. That's not text, that's gibberish, except your eyes make you think it's something like text.

Comment: Joey,  I ran the UTF-8 regex and the target string through the Visual STudio  8.0/9.0 C++ debugger and verified it that it is valid UTF8, Thank you.

Comment: Joey, Here is a hex dump of our UTF-8 text string:44 41 53 20 74 61 75 73 65 6E 64 73 63 68 C3 B6 6E 65 20 4A 75 6E 67 66 72 C3 A4 75 6C 65 69 6E 74 61 75 73 65 6E 64 73 63 68 C3 B6 6E 65 20. Thank you

Comment: "DAS tausendschÃ¶ne JungfrÃ¤ulein" is not a German string. "DAS tausendschöne Jungfräulein" is a German string, though.

Comment: Uwe Keim, Yes, DAS tausendschöne Jungfräulein, is the UTF-8 string we are passing to pcre_exec with options PCRE_UTF8 , PCRE_UCP, PCRE_CASELESS. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the returned data.

PCRE returns the starting and ending positions of the match. It has matched only once in each case, but the match includes the whole string matched, including the parts matched by "boring" things like `.*`.

So for your input string it has matched these parts:

```
DAS tausendschöne Jungfräulein tausendschçne
..............mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm..
```

Or equivalently it has matched these bytes:

```
0         1         2         3         4  4
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
DAS tausendschÃ¶ne JungfrÃ¤ulein tausendschÃ§ne
..............mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm...
```

It is behaving correctly.  From http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt :

> When a match is successful, information about  captured  substrings  is
>   returned  in  pairs  of integers, starting at the beginning of ovector,
>   and continuing up to two-thirds of its length at the  most.  The  first
>   element  of  each pair is set to the byte offset of the first character
>   in a substring, and the second is set to the byte offset of  the  first
>   character  after  the end of a substring. Note: these values are always
>   byte offsets, even in UTF-8 mode. They are not character counts.
>
> The first pair of integers, ovector[0]  and  ovector[1],  identify  the
>    portion  of  the subject string matched by the entire pattern. The next
>    pair is used for the first capturing subpattern, and so on.

Comment: Ben, Thank you for answer. We just found the correct PCRE regex to solve this problem. It is:                                          (?=.+(\x{00F6})){1}(?=.+(\x{00E4})){1}(?=.+(\x{00E7})){1}.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, We just discovered the correct PCRE regular  expression. 
(?=.+(\x{00F6})){1}(?=.+(\x{00E4})){1}(?=.+(\x{00E7})){1}

It matches DAS tausendschÃ¶ne JungfrÃ¤ulein ausendschÃ§ne at  byte positions (14,16),
(25,27)  and (42,43). Regards, Frank